# Regex to replace English Characters to Arabic by QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, field-calculator, regular-expression

I have a challenge to replace English content which comes from AutoCAD annotation to Arabic characters, Arabic fonts for AutoCAD like xarab store Arabic content as English, I just need to replace English content to Arabic by Field Calculator on QGIS.

**EXAMPLE:** English Content from AutoCAD: **lk'rm s:kdm**
Should display on the screen to: **منطقة سكنية**

Comment: Isnt this some encoding issue? Have you tried Layer Properties - Encoding and change to utf-8, or whatever is used in AutoCAD?

Comment: It's a specific autocad font for Arabic language like xarb font, the text appears on the screen as an Arabic but in properties of the text layer, content type is English

Comment: I just need a regex to match English keyboard to Arabic keyboard

Comment: The concept is match English keyboard to Arabic keyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use field calculator, first define a `key:value` map with matching values for latic/arabic characters. Something like this (here demonstrated with cyrillic characters, as I don't know arabic ones):

```
map('a','а','b','б','d','д')

meaning:
a -> а
b -> б
d -> д
```

Then you can create an array of all the characters of your input strings and for each look up the corresponding `value` to this `key` character. As we use an array, we have to convert it back to a string and remove the separating commas.

So the whole expression looks like what follows, where line 6 contains the map that you should adapt. `text` in lines 4 and 7 is the input string.

As an option, you can define lines 5 and 6 (the key:value map with matching characters) as a project variable, let's call it `translit` and then replace lines 5/6 in the following expression with `eval(@translit)` (see second screenshot).

```
replace (
    array_to_string (
        array_foreach (
            generate_series (1,length(text)),
            map_get( 
                map('a','а','b','б','d','д','e','е','g','г','ž','ж','v','в','z','з','i','и','j','й','p','п','P','П','r','р','s','с','o','о','L','Л','n','н','B','Б','R','Р','m','м','M','М'),
                substr( text, @element,1)
            )
        )
    ),
    ',',
    ''
)
```

[image]

[image]